# Can't create XML node with cyrillic name in IE11

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I need to create a xml document (with JavaScript) containing nodes, which is named in russian.

I get `InvalidCharacterError` in IE11 when trying run `doc.createElement("Выборка")`

`doc` is created with `var doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null)`

In other browsers this code is working without any issues.

How can be solved? What is the root of an issue?

**jsFiddle example**: http://jsfiddle.net/e4tUH/1/

My post on **connect.microsoft.com**: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/812130/cant-create-xml-node-with-cyrillic-name-in-ie11

**Current workaround**: Switch IE11 to IE10 with `X-UA-Compatible` meta-tag and use `window.ActiveXObject(...)` to create XML documents.

Comment: Check if your HTML document contain a `<meta>` element hinting UTF-8, also check the HTTP response headers, and whether you are specifying a `doctype`.

Comment: Ensure that your source file itself is really encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: My sources is in UTF-8. Doctype is specified.

Comment: I guess IE only allows ASCII characters as tags. Do you need exactly these representations? If not, a workaround might be to map every character to ASCII (e.g. its unicode number) and map back when using the xml.

Comment: I can't change representation. By the way, in ie10, where was ActiveXObject and XML documents through it, unicode node names working well...

Comment: Here's what I found: `.createElement("ыб")` is working for me, so does `.createElement("שלום")` (Hebrew), and `.createElement("Bыбopka")` (Cyrillic + Roman). These **fail**: `.createElement("語能力")` (Japanese), `.createElement("العربية")` (Arabic). My `document.defaultCharset` is [`"windows-1255"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) - Hebrew encoding. I couldn't find a solution though...

Comment: This looks like an IE bug in `createElement`. Try adding this to the beginning of the document: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` or setting the `Content-type` header to send UTF-8 charset.

Comment: @rvighne both is already set...

Comment: Please look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp) too.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe IE11 has an issue similar to what Firefox had in the past:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431701

That means that although your page is loading the correct encoding, IE11 is creating the new document with a default encoding which is not the expected one. There's no way to check that besides looking into IE11 source code, which we don't have.

Have you trying to add non-ASCII characters in other places besides element names? Like an attribute value or a text node?

I searched how to change the created document encoding and haven't found any solution for that.

To solve your problem I would suggest to use a DOMParser and generate a document from a XML string, like the following:

```
var parser=new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Выборка>Выборка текста</Выборка>',"text/xml");
```

All browsers seems to support it for XML parsing. More about DOMParser on the following links, including how to provide backward compatibility with older IE versions:

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

If you don't want to generate your XML just by concatenating strings, you can use some kind of XML builder like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UGYWx/6/

Then you can easily create your XML in a more safe manner:

```
var builder = new XMLBuilder("rootElement");
builder.text('Some text');

var element = builder.element("someElement", {'attr':'value'});
element.text("This is a text.");

builder.text('Some more Text');
builder.element("emptyElement");
builder.text('Even some more text');

builder.element("emptyWithAttributes", {'a1': 'val1', 'a2' : 'val2'});

$('div').text(builder.toString());
```

Comment: This is not good, cause' I need to build my XML tags not as XML but as simple text. This is much more error prone solution =( By the way, even if I parse a document with Russian tag names from string and nodes are correctly parsed (`nodeName` is correctly displayed) I can't create any other nodes with Russian names in this document.

Comment: Do you get the same error as you had before when creating the document using `createDocument()`?

Comment: Yes, same `InvalidCharacterError` as before. I can demonstrate with jsFiddle

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/a29wZ/1/ I've checked two ways. First is to create an element directly on parsed document, second is to create a new document using implementation, found on parsed document.

Comment: To solve your problem and make your code less error prone, you could use some XML builder like this: https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js

Comment: Yes, it is right workaround. But sorry, can't give you a bounty, I need a solution.

Comment: Solution is Microsoft fix their bug. That will take some time and I don't think people from SO will have that power (not in 3 days). Your code is not wrong. It works in other browsers! Solution in this case is workaround.

Comment: As usual with MS, there may be a super-duper hidden/unusual/unexpected property/method/anything that will suddenly fix this behavior... I still hope...

Comment: I don’t know the solution, but I’ve asked around to see if anyone does.

Answer (score -1):

I have always been very reluctant to use non-ASCII characters inside source code. Try escaping the string; maybe it helps.

```
doc.createElement("\u0412\u044B\u0431\u043E\u0440\u043A\u0430")
```